Change the color of the edge of the notebook
In an attempt to have a truly dark theme for Mathematica, I am using one of the dark themes, a custom CSS (inspired by this answer) and only a few WindowElements (inspired by this answer).
The result looks almost like a proper dark theme, except bright edges remain around the notebook border (between the notebook canvas and the scroll bars/ menu bar).  Here is an illustration with bright green rectangles showing the relevant areas:

Is there a way to change the color of these areas (make them dark)?  And more generally, is there a good resource with a comprehensive description of different elements of a notebook to learn from?  I'm on Linux if that matters.
